# Cannot Merge GIT branch

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge, git-branch, git-revert

I have on the branch `dev` and I created new branch from this branch
with `git checkout -b dev3`
and I do some modification on this `dev3` branch. After commit I merge it again to `dev` branch so I go back to `dev` branch with `git checkout dev` but it return error when deployment pipeline ran. and then I revert back the merge.
and now its look like this
[image: branch diagram]
Now I can't merge `dev3` into `dev`, somehow it detected as same source, even there are more than 2000 diferent file changed.
I already try using `git rebase dev` on `dev3` but not work

My question how to make `dev3` mergeable into `dev` branch again? because `dev3` and `dev` its totally different and I want to merge it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot merge the same commit twice into the same branch. You merged dev3 into dev already; you can never merge it into dev again. The revert does not change that fact.

Comment: So there is no solution for this case @matt?

Comment: May you hit the command `git log --oneline --graph --all` to display the commits tree and share this tree with us to help you, I think there is a missing thing in your question, If you revert back the merge, the result won't be like this result in image in the question